# Read XML file with break lines at column 75

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I receive a XML file from others systems with break lines at column 75. Is there a way to format or parse this kind of file?

Here a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><nfeProc versao="2.00"
xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><NFe
xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><infNFe versao="2.00"
Id="NFe33150307449335000130550010000045261000120690"><ide><cUF>33</cUF><cN
F>00012069</cNF><natOp>VENDA DE MERCADORIA ADQUIRIDA OU RECEBIDA DE
TERCEIROS</natOp><indPag>1</indPag><mod>55</mod><serie>1</serie><nNF>4526<
/nNF><dEmi>2015-03-04</dEmi><dSaiEnt>2015-03-04</dSaiEnt><hSaiEnt>10:29:32
</hSaiEnt><tpNF>1</tpNF><cMunFG>3304557</cMunFG><tpImp>1</tpImp><tpEmis>1<
/tpEmis><cDV>0</cDV><tpAmb>1</tpAmb><finNFe>1</finNFe><procEmi>0</procEmi>
<verProc>1.0.0.0</verProc></ide><emit><CNPJ>07449335000130</CNPJ><xNome>MA
NIFOLD MEDICAL COM DE PROD HOSPITALARES LTDA ME</xNome><xFant>MANIFOLD
MEDICAL</xFant><enderEmit><xLgr>AV PASTOR MARTIN LUTER KING
JUNIOR</xLgr><nro>126</nro><xCpl>BLOCO 1 - SALA 460</xCpl><xBairro>DEL
CASTILHO</xBairro><cMun>3304557</cMun><xMun>RIO DE
JANEIRO</xMun><UF>RJ</UF><CEP>20765000</CEP><cPais>1058</cPais><xPais>BRAS
IL</xPais><fone>2125831381</fone></enderEmit><IE>77984593</IE><IM>364.073-
6</IM><CNAE>4645101</CNAE><CRT>1</CRT></emit></infNFe></NFe></nfeProc>
```

I cannot just remove the break lines because there are same contents with true break lines, like descriptions of products with break lines that I would to keep preserved.

Comment: If you remove line-breaks that are within elements (setting an "in element" flag as true when you see `<` and clearing it when you see `>`), then you can at least turn it into XML, though whether other extraneous line-breaks will cause problems depends on the application.

Comment: Are you saying the .net xml parser doesn't handle reading this document?

Comment: Try to open that file with Notepade.exe or with wordpade.exe.

Comment: Yes you can parse and format that type of file. Using C#, the `XMLReader` Class should work fine for this. New lines are normalized based on the W3C XML 1.0 Recommendation.

Comment: I don't see any unusual linebreaks in your code sample. Where's the issue?

Comment: Thinking about this again ... @Urahara, is it possible you just destroyed the question with your edit? I *think* it may have been the point of the question that the code was misformatted (?)

Comment: Could it be that I unintentionally fixed it? That would be the best worst case scenario that ever happed to me.. Sorry for the inconvenience.. @John I just used jsfiddle for formatting and it highlighted the tags that were broken.

Comment: @JasonAusborn: Assuming that the original formatting before the edit did indeed replicate the look of the file, that is incorrect. `XmlReader` will choke on tags whose names are broken apart by linebreaks, such as `<cNF>` at the end of line 4/beginning of line 5.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, this is interesting. Testing it now.

Comment: Guys, the problem is not format one file XML. The other system generate the hundreds of XML file by hour and I cannot reformat each file manually. I would like to use something more automatically to do this for me.